# Compiling SDL and OpenGL inside of Code Blocks on Ubuntu

Tags: opengl, sdl, codeblocks, compiler-options

So anytime I compile my code using the terminal I have to compile with:

```
-lSDL -lGL -lGLU
```

How do I do this in Code Blocks?  I have tried putting those into the build options for the project, but this did not fix anything.

edit: I have also tried Set Program Arguments, and it has not worked...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option `-l` is a linker option. You may add the libraries you want to link with in the linker settings tab (in the build options). Using the Add button you may add libraries GL, GLU and SDL.